# Not able to run command after upgrade - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, serialize

I have upgraded the Magento version after that I have run cache clean, flush and permission command.

above cache-related commands are working good but `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command isn't working.

**It gives this error:**

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                                
  Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 1977 of 2818 bytes in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Unserialize/Unserialize.php on line 21
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which Magento version you use?

Comment: Magento EE 2.1.18

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check all the necessary libraries for your Magento 2 version. There are must be :

> ext-bcmath,ext-ctype,ext-curl,ext-dom,ext-gd,ext-hash,ext-iconv,ext-intl,ext-mbstring,ext-openssl,ext-pdo_mysql,ext-simplexml,ext-soap,ext-spl,ext-xsl,ext-zip,lib-libxml

The second step - check your app/etc/env.php file (Is where are your password/DB name/ DB user is right?).

> Try to run composer install or composer update

Check your current PHP version:

> php -v in console

if it is not correct , switch it.

> remove directories : var/cache var/tmp var/view_preprocessed
>   genereted/*

Comment: Thank You for your reply,Due to Amsty feed module commands are not working, i have disable it so now it's working